# Issue on Targetting A Class which Has One Specific ID

Tags: css

Can you please let me know how I can target an element with a class which has only specific ID?

For example in the following code I need to change the size of only the class which also has the foo ID.

```
<ul>
    <li class="sam">This is not Target</li>
    <li class="sam">This is not Target</li>
    <li class="sam" id="foo">This is The Target</li>
    <li class="sam">This is not Target</li>
    <li class="sam">This is not Target</li>
</ul>
```

I already tried this

```
#foo .sam {color:green}
```

but it didn't work. I know that is simply possible in css to target the id element but in this scenarios I have to change the class properties only for that specific item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the space:

```css
#foo.sam { color: green }
```